# Adicionar um método estático, que cria vários objetos e armazena em campos estáticos em C#

Tags: c#

Exercicio: Adicione um método estático na classe StudentTest, que cria vários objetos do tipo Student e os armazena em campos estáticos. Crie uma propriedade estática da classe para acessá-los. Escreva um programa de teste, que exibe as informações sobre eles no console.

Dificuldade:Ja tenho a classe Student criada, com  um sobrecarga de construtores e tenho dificuldade me criar o método que crie vários objectos do tipo "Student" e ammazenar em
um campo estático.
Tentei criar um método que receba um array de "Student" e os dados do estudante por parametro para criar várias instancias de um objecto do tipo "Student" e armazenar no array que recebe-se por paramentro .Mas quando chamo o método na class main e adiciono os dados, ele perde os dados  e só considera dados do último estudante adiocionado.
Alguma sugestão para corrigir isso?

Classe Student

```
namespace Job1
{
internal class Student
    {
    
        private String fullName, course, subject, university, email;
        private int cell;
        public static int nrObj = 0;
   
        public string FullName { get => fullName; set => fullName = value; }
        public string Course { get => course; set => course = value; }
        public string Subject { get => subject; set => subject = value; }
        public string University { get => university; set => university = value; }
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
        public int Cell { get => cell; set => cell = value; }

        public Student(string fullName, string course, string subject, string university, string email, int cell)
        {
            this.FullName = fullName;
            this.Course = course;
            this.Subject = subject;
            this.University = university;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Cell = cell;
            nrObj++;
        }

        public Student(string fullName, string course, string subject, string university)
        {
            this.FullName = fullName;
            this.Course = course;
            this.Subject = subject;
            this.University = university;
            nrObj++;
        }

        public Student(string fullName, string email, int cell)
        {
            this.FullName = fullName;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Cell = cell;
            nrObj++;
        }

        public void showInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===========Student Info==============" +
                "\nFullname: {0} \nCourse: {1} \nSubject: {2} \nUniversity{3} \nEmail: {4}" +
                "\nCell: {5}", this.FullName, this.Course, this.Subject, this.University, this.Email, this.Cell);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "===========Student Info==============" +
                "\nFullname:" +this.fullName +
                " \nCourse:" + this.course +
                " \nSubject: " + this.subject +
                " \nUniversity" + this.university +
                " \nEmail:" +  this.email +
                "\nCell: " +this.cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Main

```
namespace Job1
{
    internal class StudentTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
     

            String name, course, sub, uni, em;
            int size, cell;

            Console.WriteLine("Quantos estudantes quer introduzir");
            size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

            //Ãrray de estudantes
            Student [] student = new Student[size];
            
            //Ciclo para introduzir os dados do estudante
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digite seu nome");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza o curso");
                course = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza a a discplina");
                sub= Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza o email");
                em = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza universidade");
                uni = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza o cell");
                cell = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //Adicionado os estudantes
                addStudent(student, size, name, course, sub, uni, em, cell);
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student[i]);
            }
        }

        public static void addStudent(Student[] st, int size, string fullName, string course, string subject, string university, string email, int cell)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                st[i] = new Student(fullName, course, subject, university, email, cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta na montagem da sua lógica na classe `Main`.
Primeiramente você criar uma variável estática para que possa armazenar os dados de entrada (estudantes).
Depois você precisa criar um método estático para adicionar um estudante de cada vez.
E por último dentro do seu `Main` você deve setar o tamanho do `array` conforme a entrada do usuário.

Fiz um [exemplo funcional](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T4C1j2) no `dotnetfiddle.net` que adiciona nomes, você pode usar a mesma lógica e adicionar ao seu código.

Código

```
using System;
                    
public class Program {
        
    static string[] listaNomes;
    
    public static void Main() {
        string[] nome = {"Joao","Almeida","Maria","Lucia"};
        
        listaNomes = new string[4];
        
        // aqui simula a entrada de dados do usuario
        for(int i = 0; i < nome.Length; i++)
        {           
            //adicionar os nomes na variável estática pelo método estático
            AdicionarNomes(nome[i], i);
        }
        
        //exibir os dados da variável estática
        for(int i = 0; i < nome.Length; i++)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(listaNomes[i]);
        }
    }
    
    private static void AdicionarNomes(string nomeParametro, int pos)
    {
        listaNomes[pos] = nomeParametro;
    }   
}
```

Documentação da MS sobre [modificador estático](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

Documentação da MS sobre [arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).